# How to use case_when with mutate_all to insert variable value

Tags: r, dplyr, case-when

I have a seemingly small problem. I want to use `mutate_all()` in conjunction with `case_when()`. A sample data frame:

```
tbl <- tibble( 
  x = c(0, 1, 2, 3, NA),
  y = c(0, 1, NA, 2, 3),
  z = c(0, NA, 1, 2, 3),
  date = rep(today(), 5)
)
```

I first made another data frame replacing all the NA's with zero's and the values with a 1 with the following piece of code.

```
tbl %>%
 mutate_all(
    funs(
      case_when(
        . %>% is.na() ~ 0,
        TRUE ~ 1
      )))
```

Now I want to replace the NA values with blanks (`""`) and leave the other values as it is. However, I don't know how to set the TRUE value in a way that it keeps the value of the column.

Any suggestions would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To leave the `NA` as `""`, we can use `replace_na` from `tidyr`

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
tbl %>%
     mutate_all(replace_na, "")
# A tibble: 5 x 3
#  x     y     z    
#  <chr> <chr> <chr>
#1 0     0     0    
#2 1     1     ""   
#3 2     ""    1    
#4 3     2     2    
#5 ""    3     3
```

---

With `case_when` or `if_else`, we have to make sure the `type` are the same across.  Here, we are converting to `character` when we insert the `""`, so make sure the other values are also coerced to `character` class

```
tbl %>%
   mutate_all(~ case_when(is.na(.) ~ "", TRUE ~ as.character(.)))
```

If we want to use only specific columns, then we can use `mutate_at`

```
tbl %>%
   mutate_at(vars(x:y), ~ case_when(is.na(.) ~ "", TRUE ~ as.character(.)))
```

---

Also, to simplify the code in OP's post, it can be directly coerced to integer with `as.integer` or `+`

```
tbl %>% 
     mutate_all(~ as.integer(!is.na(.)))
```

Or if we are using `case_when`

```
tbl %>%
       mutate_all(~ case_when(is.na(.)~ 0, TRUE ~ 1))
```

Comment: Thanks! That was what I was looking for. One more question. I have a few datetime columns and I would like to not change the type of the columns to character. Any way to do that in `mutate_all()` or do I have to use `mutate_if()`?

Comment: @ akrun Accepted and thanls for the fast reply!